# Power Conditioner: Is it worth investing a little more?

Tags: noise, power, hum, harmonics

Since my studio gear has gotten some additions (new synth etc.) I'm running into power issues. First of all I get a hint of 6,5kHz (+harmonics) on the instrument input of my RME Fireface UC. Second I'm running out of AC outlets :)
So I looked into getting a Power Conditioner. There are several brands and different levels of 'conditioning'. Furman seems to be the 'standard' but I also saw a new product called Nusonic Powerplant.

What are your experiences with these devices? Do you really need 'digital filtered' outputs and 'analog filtered' outputs? Or can you simply buy 2 separate devices for digital and analog stuff?

Not an electronic engineering expert so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 1):

A Furman should do the trick.
I run both analog & digital from mine and I have never had a problem to date.
Its better to buy new than 2nd hand as like all power equipment they do have a lifespan.
If you go into any decent studio they will have an array of Furman Power Conditioners, this is the trusted name in the industry for the reliability of the product.

Hope This Helps - S

Answer (score 0):

I also run Furman gear in my personal studio as well as some of the theaters I have worked in with great success. I have run both digital and analog equipment off the units with out a problem. What I find is more key than the unit its self is to make sure that all the units you are running (if you are running more than one) are on the same circuit. Even the most basic Furman units clean up the power nicely but I have had issue when my mixer is on a unit running on a different circuit (in the fuse panel of the building) than say my monitors. On top of that most modern gear power supplies (at least gear that is above the most entry level) cleans the power for you nicely. As mentioned, buy them new, its worth it.